# How to omit a field validation in Grails controller's hasErrors() methods

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am using Grails 2.4.2. I have a domain class where I have a field of another domain class object. When I generate view for my domain it creates a select box for that class object. I commented the select box and pass the id from view to controller. In controller I am trying to add the class object by domain.get() method of Grails.

But for hasErrors() method in controller it shows always validation problem and redirecting me with errors without saving. If I comment the hasErrors() then it save properly. But I need to use hasErrors() for other field validation.

Here is my code. My domain:

```
    class ThanaAgent {

    String agentName
    DistrictAgent districtAgent

    ...
}
```

My Controller save method:

```
@Transactional
def save(ThanaAgent thanaAgentInstance) {

    if (thanaAgentInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    DistrictAgent districtAgent = DistrictAgent.get(Long.parseLong(params.districtAgentId))
    thanaAgentInstance.districtAgent = districtAgent

    if (thanaAgentInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond thanaAgentInstance.errors, view: 'create'
        return
    }

    thanaAgentInstance.save flush: true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'thanaAgent.label', default: 'ThanaAgent'), thanaAgentInstance.id])
            redirect thanaAgentInstance
        }
        '*' { respond thanaAgentInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

here I am assigning the object as districtAgent .

In my view instead of select >>>

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>District Agent</label>
        ...
        <g:hiddenField name="districtAgentId" id="districtAgentId"
                       value="1"/>
        %{--<g:select id="districtAgent" name="districtAgent.id" from="${book.DistrictAgent.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${thanaAgentInstance?.districtAgent?.id}" class="form-control"/>--}%
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh it was so simple. just edit the name of the field as select box as follow :

```
<g:hiddenField name="districtAgent.id" id="districtAgent"
                       value="${thanaAgentInstance?.districtAgent?.id}"/>
```